# Regex for custom Date format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the regular expression as:

```
var validDate = /^\d{4}-((0\d)|(1[012]))-(([012]\d)|3[01]) (([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]).([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9])$/i.test(value);
```

The value I am providing is `Nov 21, 2014 12:00:00 AM`.

Can anybody please help me in providing with the actual date expression (value) that will actually test the regex?

Comment: try this one `2014-02-31 23:00:59999` that will pass the above test, exposing two bugs, one easily fixed, the other not so easy.

Comment: the above test requires a digit one place after the seconds part of the time. the expression looks like a failed attempt to describe some variant of ISO-9601.  `2014-02-31 23:00:666` also "works"

Comment: Do not parse dates with RegExp. Use a date parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anybody please help me in providing with the actual date expression (value) that will actually test the regex.

I won't provide the value, but rather the format of what the regex matches:

```
####-mm-dd HH:MM:ss.###
```

Where `#` denotes a number, `mm` denotes a month, `dd` denotes a date, `HH` denotes an hour in 24-hour format, `MM` denotes minutes and `ss` denotes seconds.

Comment: and (bug) the `.` could be any character at all!

Comment: @Jasen Oh yea, nicely spotted.

Comment: Also, the regex can accept any date, even if it is not valid like the 30th of February.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use built-in `Date.parse`:

```
var epochVal = Date.parse("Nov 21, 2014 12:00:00 AM")
//=> 1416546000000
```

OR:

```
var dt = new Date( Date.parse("Nov 21, 2014 12:00:00 AM") )
//=> Fri Nov 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one `2014-02-13 23:00:59.0`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @remus It answers this bit. `Can anybody please help me in providing with the actual date expression (value) that will actually test the regex.`, well "yes" would be technically more accurate but it too short to satisfy stack exchange.